# access: implementing autonumber type in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

i have a database that is in access and i am converting it to mysql

in access there is a type called autonumber. is there such a thing in mysql? if not, what would be an easy way to implement such a type (or not necessarily implement the type but to have the same functionality) ?

Comment: This is neither here nor there, but I find it annoying that questions like this regarding Access are marked for closure as belonging on SuperUser, yet, when such a simple question as this is asked of some other database or development plagform, nobody suggests it's not a programming question, or too elementary for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).  You can apply the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute to a field.

Comment: Alternately, you can use the `SERIAL` type, which is a synonym for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`

Comment: One could also create an ODBC DSN for a target MySQL database and export a Jet/ACE table with an Autonumber and see what the resulting data type is in MySQL.